# How to update the display of Pygame only when there is fresh incoming data from another Python script?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a Python script that receives data through Bluetooth at not so regular intervals. Specifically it receives the coordinates of an image through Bluetooth. Using those coordinates I want to update the display of an image in a separate Pygame script. I don't want the Pygame display to close and open again. The Pygame script should run continuously and it should update the display of the image only when it receives new data.

Here is my Bluetooth script:

```
import bluetooth
server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
port = 1
server_sock.bind(("", port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock, address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ", address

while True:

    data = client_sock.recv(1024)
    print "received [%s]" % data
```

Any guidelines on how to achieve this behaviour would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    # Initialise screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((150, 50))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Basic Pygame program')

    # Fill background
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250, 250, 250))

    # Display some text
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    text = font.render("Hello There", 1, (10, 10, 10))
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
    background.blit(text, textpos)

    # Blit everything to the screen
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Event loop
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        #do something with the data
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I just got that from the example. You should be able to do whatever you want inside the game loop.